# Having trouble getting my run() method to loop

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, applet

I'm using `Eclipse IDE,` Java Project, I'm extending the `superclass` Applet and having trouble getting my Run method to activate at all, here's the source code:

```
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Help..");

        //Updates the character
        CHAR1.update();

        //Updates the background
        bg1.update();
        bg2.update();

        repaint();

        try {

            Thread.sleep(17);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get it to change any information or print out the "Help.." Why isn't the run method looping?

I've been sitting here putting `println` statements everywhere testing to see what responds, this is the only thing I could find that was wrong with my source thus far. It doesn't say any errors, it just doesn't loop the method. (I tried @Override, but it said something about Annotation and was an error, I ran it with @Override and nothing changed.)

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I wrote the code I used to declare a thread but must not have saved it. How could I have forgotten?! Well, thanks. This is my first Applet so I still don't exactly fully understand things like Thread, trying to get the hang of it. Thanks man. I spent hours on this trying to figure it out when it was just that I forgot to make the thread e.e

Comment: Can you share the code you use to start this Thread please ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you call the .start() method of the Thread object, and NOT the .run() method, even if your loop is implemented there.

If you call directly the .run() method, then the method is executed but in the same thread of the caller, and not in a separated one: I guess that probably the caller Thread is the GUI thread, and so your loop freeze the GUI and does not actually show the updates.

Comment: Yeah, I did awhile back, called the thread in start and implemented in Run, must have just deleted it or something.

Answer (score 0):

How many classes have you created? You must declare the class like this if you use only one class for applet and for thread:

```
Public class ClsName extends Applet implements runnable { }
```

You must share your code for perfect solution.

Comment: I have three classes, Main, Background, and Character1, I have the solution thanks to the comment but I don't know how to give the comment the answer.. I simply misdeclared my Thread. I also do have this:

public class MainClass extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {